# Editing file in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, libreoffice

I have uploaded a file to ubuntu one. I got to edit it and update it very often. Is there any I can in which I can edit file(spreadsheet) in ubuntu one?

I used Google Drive, I could create and manage file there.

Can I sync my file in Documents folder with 'file in ubuntu one' such that, when I edit the file in my Computer, file should be updated inside ubuntu one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. U can. Go to Documents and create a folder with the name u specified(file in ubuntu one). Then open "Ubuntu one" (app) from your system and click "Add a folder from this computer" and choose that folder which u created and make sure there is a tick mark in the column "Sync Locally". Now if u edit any file within that folder it will be automatically updated to your Ubuntu one each time u press "save".

Comment: Thanks. I noticed, the file uploaded is in '/home/ubuntu one.